# Field level injection with Gin

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, gwt-gin

I'm trying to do field-level injection so I don't have to pass "models" when my controllers are instantiated, like,

```
UserController controller = new UserController(/*No need to pass models here*/);
```

However my application throws NullPointerException, here my code:

**UserController.java**

```
    public class UserController implements Controller {
        @Inject private UserModel model;
        public UserController() {
          model.doSomething(); // NullPointerException
        }
    }
```

**ClientGinModule.java**

```
public class ClientGinModule extends AbstractGinModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(UserModel.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are properly injecting you deps? If you use new UserController(), then that's your problem, you should use `injector.getInstance(UserController.class);`.

Comment: I see, so the field-injection is ok? I mean, if I use getInstance method the UserModel will not be null?

Comment: Yes, using getInstance(UserController.class) all injectable fields will be injected. Just note that in the constructor, the fields are not injected yet, but after they are. If you need some values in the constructor, the only way around is to add those as injectable parameters of your constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use In Guice

```
UserController controller = injector.getInstance(UserController.class);
```

Use in Gin:

```
// Declare a method returning a UserController on your interface extending Ginjector
public UserController getUserController();

// When you need the controller, just call:
injector.getUserController();
```

to get a fully-injected controller.

Comment: I'm using Guice adaptation for GWT which is GIN so I think I can't call injector.getIntance though

Comment: @xybrek I think then that you should simply declare a method `public UserController getUserController()` on you interface extends Ginjector and it will do the rest. Then to get your controller, simply call `injector.getUserController()`

Comment: @downvoter care to explain why the downvote? especially on an answer provided over 6 months ago?

Answer (score 0):

Your `model` field will be null while constructor is still running. It will be injected by GIN after the moment when `UserController` object is fully created. Here [GWT GIN Field Level Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458683/gwt-gin-field-level-injection) you can find nice explanation about it.